How to create a repeating SVG pattern?
I have been given a design that uses this pattern in the background of a website

I think an SVG pattern would be ideal for something like this. I can make an individual column of these shapes, but I am not sure if that could be better generated in a different way. What I am doing feels wrong and inefficient, and it would not scale to stretch across a screen for a background image.


svg {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

svg * { 
  transform-box: fill-box;
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100" height="780" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <path id="hex" fill="#D4C1DE" fill-opacity="0.3" d="M0 25.980762113533157L15 0L45 0L60 25.980762113533157L45 51.96152422706631L15 51.96152422706631Z">
  </defs>
  
    <use xlink:href="#hex" transform-origin="center" x="0" y="0"   transform="scale(0.20)" />
    <use xlink:href="#hex" transform-origin="center" x="0" y="400" transform="scale(0.30)" />
    <use xlink:href="#hex" transform-origin="center" x="0" y="450" transform="scale(0.40)" />
    <use xlink:href="#hex" transform-origin="center" x="0" y="500" transform="scale(0.50)" />
    <use xlink:href="#hex" transform-origin="center" x="0" y="550" transform="scale(0.60)" />
    <use xlink:href="#hex" transform-origin="center" x="0" y="600" transform="scale(0.70)" />
    <use xlink:href="#hex" transform-origin="center" x="0" y="650" transform="scale(0.80)" />
    <use xlink:href="#hex" transform-origin="center" x="0" y="700" transform="scale(0.90)" />
    <use xlink:href="#hex" transform-origin="center" x="0" y="730" />
</svg>



What is a more practical way to achieve the desired effect here?

I see rows not columns

I guess you could look at it either way. I see columns, but every other column is shifted up vertically

Small change to Chris his great answer

Modern Browsers accept raw SVG as dataURI, no need for Base64

only have to replace linebreaks and " and #


a  <svg-background> Web Component allows for SVG editting and see the result immediatly




customElements.define( "svg-background", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => { // wait till <template> is parsed as DOM
        let svg = this.querySelector("template").innerHTML
                      .replace("#D4C1DE",this.getAttribute("fill") || "#D4C1DE")
                      .replaceAll("\n", "")    // replace linebreaks
                      .replaceAll('"', "'")    // replace double quotes
                      .replaceAll("#", "%23"); // escape #
        Object.assign(this.style, { // or document.body.style
          display: "block",
          width: "100vw",
          height: "100vh",
          backgroundImage: `url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,${svg}")`,
          backgroundSize: "contain",
        });
      });
    }
  }
);
<svg-background fill="green">
  <template>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 500" fill="white">
      <defs>
        <path id="h" fill="#D4C1DE" fill-opacity="0.3" d="M-10-17.32 10-17.32 20 0 10 17.32-10 17.32-20 0Z" />
      </defs>
      <g id="g" transform="translate(0 20)">
        <use href="#h" transform="translate(0   0) scale(.2)" />
        <use href="#h" transform="translate(0  50) scale(.3)" />
        <use href="#h" transform="translate(0 100) scale(.4)" />
        <use href="#h" transform="translate(0 150) scale(.5)" />
        <use href="#h" transform="translate(0 200) scale(.6)" />
        <use href="#h" transform="translate(0 250) scale(.7)" />
        <use href="#h" transform="translate(0 305) scale(.8)" />
        <use href="#h" transform="translate(0 360) scale(.9)" />
        <use href="#h" transform="translate(0 420) scale(1)" />
      </g>
      <use href="#g" transform="translate(25 30)"/>
      <use href="#g" transform="translate(50 0)"/>
    </svg>
  </template>
</svg-background>




Wow, this is a super cool way to solve this problem - thank you!  I might tweak a bit how the individual hexagons are scaled and spaced out, but this pretty much does what I need!

You can use the <pattern> element for repeating the elements.
Here the pattern is made of a column of <use> elements (just like you did it). The column is repeated by two more <use> elements. Each column has a transform/translate so that there is one column of hexagons in the middle and half a column to the left and half a column to the right in the pattern. Repeating the pattern, the halfs will align and form a hole hexagon.
I refactored you hexagon so that the numbers look nicer AND the center of the hexagon is 0,0. Then you don't need to handle the origin of the hexagon.


svg {
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
  <defs>
    <path id="hex" fill="#D4C1DE" fill-opacity="0.3" d="M-10-17.32 10-17.32 20 0 10 17.32-10 17.32-20 0Z" />
    <pattern id="p1" viewBox="0 0 50 500" width="10%" height="100%">
      <g id="g1" transform="translate(0 20)">
        <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0   0) scale(.2)" />
        <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0  50) scale(.3)" />
        <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 100) scale(.4)" />
        <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 150) scale(.5)" />
        <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 200) scale(.6)" />
        <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 250) scale(.7)" />
        <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 305) scale(.8)" />
        <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 360) scale(.9)" />
        <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 420) scale(1)" />
      </g>
      <use href="#g1" transform="translate(25 30)"/>
      <use href="#g1" transform="translate(50 0)"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect width="500" height="500" fill="url(#p1)" />
</svg>



Update
OK, that is just me. The pattern should cover the background of a HTML page. Never mind about the <pattern> element. A CSS background image will be repeated by default. In the following example I use this SVG image:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 500" width="50">
  <defs>
    <path id="hex" fill="#D4C1DE" fill-opacity="0.3" d="M-10-17.32 10-17.32 20 0 10 17.32-10 17.32-20 0Z" />
  </defs>
  <rect width="500" height="500" fill="url(#p1)" />
  <g id="g1" transform="translate(0 20)">
    <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0   0) scale(.2)" />
    <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0  50) scale(.3)" />
    <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 100) scale(.4)" />
    <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 150) scale(.5)" />
    <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 200) scale(.6)" />
    <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 250) scale(.7)" />
    <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 305) scale(.8)" />
    <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 360) scale(.9)" />
    <use href="#hex" transform="translate(0 420) scale(1)" />
  </g>
  <use href="#g1" transform="translate(25 30)"/>
  <use href="#g1" transform="translate(50 0)"/>
</svg>

So, the same as above, just without the pattern. And then you can insert that as an background image. It can be adjusted to the height (here, using background-size: contain;) or you can leave that out and the SVG will just be repeated using the defined width of 50px.


body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA1MCA1MDAiIHdpZHRoPSI1MCI+CiAgPGRlZnM+CiAgICA8cGF0aCBpZD0iaGV4IiBmaWxsPSIjRDRDMURFIiBmaWxsLW9wYWNpdHk9IjAuMyIgZD0iTS0xMC0xNy4zMiAxMC0xNy4zMiAyMCAwIDEwIDE3LjMyLTEwIDE3LjMyLTIwIDBaIiAvPgogIDwvZGVmcz4KICA8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iNTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUwMCIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNwMSkiIC8+CiAgPGcgaWQ9ImcxIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSgwIDIwKSI+CiAgICA8dXNlIGhyZWY9IiNoZXgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAgICAwKSBzY2FsZSguMikiIC8+CiAgICA8dXNlIGhyZWY9IiNoZXgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAgIDUwKSBzY2FsZSguMykiIC8+CiAgICA8dXNlIGhyZWY9IiNoZXgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAgMTAwKSBzY2FsZSguNCkiIC8+CiAgICA8dXNlIGhyZWY9IiNoZXgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAgMTUwKSBzY2FsZSguNSkiIC8+CiAgICA8dXNlIGhyZWY9IiNoZXgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAgMjAwKSBzY2FsZSguNikiIC8+CiAgICA8dXNlIGhyZWY9IiNoZXgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAgMjUwKSBzY2FsZSguNykiIC8+CiAgICA8dXNlIGhyZWY9IiNoZXgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAgMzA1KSBzY2FsZSguOCkiIC8+CiAgICA8dXNlIGhyZWY9IiNoZXgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAgMzYwKSBzY2FsZSguOSkiIC8+CiAgICA8dXNlIGhyZWY9IiNoZXgiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDAgNDIwKSBzY2FsZSgxKSIgLz4KICA8L2c+CiAgPHVzZSBocmVmPSIjZzEiIHRyYW5zZm9ybT0idHJhbnNsYXRlKDI1IDMwKSIvPgogIDx1c2UgaHJlZj0iI2cxIiB0cmFuc2Zvcm09InRyYW5zbGF0ZSg1MCAwKSIvPgo8L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}




Amazing thank you! I can tweak the specifics from here. SVG is amazing and has so many features I learn about every time I use it

How can I make this pattern stretch fill width across the page and keep the same propotions?
